# pattern for generating JSON output

Tags: xslt-3.0

I'm trying to map XML to JSON using XSLT 3.0

my broad plan is to take the input, map it to some elements in memory, and then map that to 'map's and 'array's to by applying templates and then letting the XSLT serialise that as JSON.

Here is my initial effort:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="json" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
   <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="dsl" as="element()">
        <epg lastBuildDate="10/4/2019 9:46:00 AM">
        </epg>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="output">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$dsl" mode="interpret"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:sequence select="$output"/>
   </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="epg" mode="interpret">
        <xsl:sequence select="map { 
            'lastBuildDate' : @lastBuildDate 
            }"/>        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

sadly I get

```
Cannot add a map to an XDM node tree
```

in the 'interpret' template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs with

```
<xsl:variable name="output">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$dsl" mode="interpret"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

as that is an implicit use of

```
<xsl:variable name="output">
  <xsl:document>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$dsl" mode="interpret"/>
  </xsl:document>
</xsl:variable>
```

While maps can contain nodes as values, nodes can't contain maps.

For that simple example it should work to use

```
<xsl:variable name="output" as="item()*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$dsl" mode="interpret"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

or even

```
<xsl:variable name="output" as="item()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$dsl" mode="interpret"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

or

```
<xsl:variable name="output" as="map(*)">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$dsl" mode="interpret"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: hmmm....and here was me thinking 'as' was just some sort of type hint.

Comment: so where do i find out how this magic 'as' attribute works? what does it do? it seems to do a cast, rather than simply track type information

Comment: That is certainly explained in detail for instance, in Michael Kay's XSLT 2.0 reference book. Of course in the spec as well, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#temporary-trees and https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#variable-values, https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#variables

Comment: actually there is a 2nd issue, i have to explicity 'cast' "@lastBuildDate => xs:string()"...it now works

Answer (score 0):

this works, I'll mark the other answer as correct though there is a 2nd issue where you have to 'cast' the attribute to a string

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:output method="json" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="dsl" as="element()">
            <epg lastBuildDate="10/4/2019 9:46:00 AM">
            </epg>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="output" as="map(*)*">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$dsl" mode="interpret"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:sequence select="$output"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="epg" as="map(*)" mode="interpret">
        <xsl:sequence select="map {
            'lastBuildDate' : @lastBuildDate => xs:string() 
            }"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```